# Change product image for configurable products

Tags: configurable-product, ce-1.7.0.2, product-images, product-view

I was looking for a way that let me change the product image based on the attribute selected for the configurable product. e.g.

Configurable Product With Color Options  :  1) Red 2) Green

If the Red is selected by user is should change the main image on the details page with the one from associated products.

I have looked over this one [Simple Configurable Product](http://www.magentocommerce.com/magento-connect/simple-configurable-products.html)

But in the reviews some one is saying that image changing is not working also this is adding and extra functionality for pricing based on associated products this is not what i was thinking.

Any one having any idea how this can achieve without having to put too much work.
Thanks.

Answer (score 29):

The question is tagged with [ce-1.7.0.2](/questions/tagged/ce-1.7.0.2) but for future reference, if you are using [ce-1.9.1.0](/questions/tagged/ce-1.9.1.0) [ee-1.14.1](/questions/tagged/ee-1.14.1) or higher, the feature is already built in, with the so-called Configurable Swatches which allow "Product Image Swap".

You can enable this feature in *System > Configuration > CATALOG > Configurable Swatches*

> ## [Product Image Swap](http://www.magentocommerce.com/knowledge-base/entry/ee1141-ce191-configurable-swatches#swap)
>
> The following animation shows how this works on product listing and
>   product detail pages:
>
> [image: animation]
>
> ### Swap Images Defined by Option Label
>
> One way to configure swap images is to upload images to a configurable
>   product with labels exactly matching the specific option labels (for
>   example, `Royal Blue`).
>
> Here is an example of a configurable product image gallery images that
>   contains images for three colors:
>
> [image: option label configuration]
>
> ### Swap Images Defined by Base Image
>
> Another way to configure swap images is to upload base images to each
>   child product of the configurable product.
>
> Here is an example of a Royal Blue child product with an attached base
>   image:
>
> [image: base image configuration]

**Source and full documentation:** http://docs.magento.com/m1/ce/user_guide/catalog/product-configurable-swatch.html

Comment: Nice Demo... This will come in handy.

Comment: I am using configurable swatches as you suggested, but the problem is it gets deselected after I select option two in configurable product. So for example I select colour, the correct image is selected and then I select size and the image is gone leaving default magento "no image". Any idea how to fix that?

Answer (score 18):

It's a fair amount of work to implement that yourself, but there are a number of extensions that implement that, both free and commercial.

- SCP is probably the most prominent free extension, and it works well if the theme templates haven't diverged too far from the default. http://www.magentocommerce.com/magento-connect/simple-configurable-products.html
- Color Swatches is well known, too. http://www.magentocommerce.com/magento-connect/color-swatches-magento-extension.html
- If you need much flexibility about which selected option details are displayed, BCP (Better Configurable Products) is a good choice, although it more expensive and you need a good knowledge of XPATH to extensively customize it. http://www.magentocommerce.com/magento-connect/better-configurable-products.html
- Another one I've seen used but I don't have personal experience with is http://amasty.com/image-based-configurable-products.html

There are many more as a quick google will show, but thats all I can talk about regarding to first or second hand experience.

Comment: Thanks a lot for suggestion but i have choosed to go with http://www.magentocommerce.com/magento-connect/catalog/product/view/id/17414/ installed smoothly working as expected.

Comment: @ravisoni I use SCP and it works prefectly for me (with appropriate mods for Magento 1.8.1). What extension did you use (your link above doesn't go to an extension any more)?

Comment: I'm using SCP but on the grid or list view the image isn't changed depending on the filter chosen. I have carpets which come in colours, these colours are set on the simple products but when filtering it only ever shows the base image. Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

for changing image of configurable product's options you may try our extension.
http://extensions.sashas.org/customer-experience/configurable-image-swticher.html
It will take image from the actual simple related product.

Comment: Some information on how this extension works and how the user and implement it into their shop would be great to help them decide if it is worth paying for the extension.

Comment: Basically it changes main image on product page to assosicated product image. But there is one thing that in custom themes may be different zoom & image view modules then it needs customization according to custom zoom. Its why there is installation option. But you can always try yourself and ask for installation if you need help.

Comment: Link in this answer no longer works, would be worth editing this with an updated link