# Switching picture on a Configurable Product

Tags: configurable-product, ce-1.9.0.1, swatches

I use the 1.9.0.1 version of magento and I would like for configurable products when the user selected a color, pictures of the product changes.

I saw that there are modules for this but none are compatible with the 1.9.0.1 release.

Is there a patch or a module for the 1.9.0.1 version?

thanks

Comment: I recommend Easylife Switcher by @Marius: https://github.com/tzyganu/Switcher (actually works better than the core module in Magento 1.9.1+)

Comment: More alternatives are listed here: http://magento.stackexchange.com/q/4482/243

Answer (score 1):

This is a default feature in Magento 1.9.1, no additional modules needed.

You could consider updating to this Magento version.

Check here:
http://www.magentocommerce.com/knowledge-base/entry/ee1141-ce191-configurable-swatches