# Configurable swatches

Tags: magento-1.9, configurable-product, swatches, color-swatches

We have a online shop with shoes.

For example i would like to have a configurable product "Shoes XXX" with following simple products:

- "Shoes XXX Color Black Size 40"
- "Shoes XXX Color Black Size 41"
- "Shoes XXX Color Black Size 42"
- "Shoes XXX Color Green Size 39"
- "Shoes XXX Color Green Size 41"
- "Shoes XXX Color Red Size 38"
- "Shoes XXX Color Red Size 40"

I use the core functionality of magento 1.9 (and i found and this extension https://github.com/wigman/AjaxSwatches , but i haven't test yet)

I do not want to upload separate images for the products of the same color (but different sized). is there any way for that?

Also in color swatches (core functionality of magento 1.9) i would like displayed a small product image in selected color. how i do that?

Answer (score 4):

The swatch extensions I know, as well as the 1.9 core module, use images of the simple products, so there is no way around duplicating the images. But you can avoid duplicating the actual image files if you rewrite the media attribute model. Here is a module that does it, it compares the MD5 hash of uploaded images and reuses existing files: https://github.com/fbrnc/Aoe_ReuseImages

For the swatch display, see [Change product image for configurable products](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/4482/change-product-image-for-configurable-products/45578#45578)