# Magento Configurable Product & Pricing

Tags: magento-1.9, configurable-product

I am using Magento 1.9.2.2 and I added configurable product but the problem is it is not reflecting it's child product price. and sometimes images are also not reflecting while selecting a color. I added all the simple product images to the configurable product.

Answer (score 1):

Check this link: [Change product image for configurable products](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/4482/change-product-image-for-configurable-products)

Also there's an official Magento documentation: http://www.magentocommerce.com/knowledge-base/entry/ee1141-ce191-configurable-swatches

Hope this helps