# Magento 1.9.2.4 configurable swatches don't change main image

Tags: magento-1.9, product, configurable-product, product-attribute, swatches

I've been stuck for hours on this one.

Product I'm working on: [this site](http://seenthefuture.com/unisex/donald-trump-hillary-got-schlonged-sweatshirt)

I've made this **configurable product**, enabled swatches and added photos for each of those associated products. However when I click on color and size, can't get main image to change.

How do I fix it ?

Comment: have you set the individual images to the associated products?

Comment: yes I have set those. you can see that I have set them if you add grey sweatshirt to basket and click view basket, grey sweatshirt photo shows up

Comment: did you give sreen shot of associate product ? that you set image for that product. set image for all small , thumbnail and large image

Comment: You fill label images from configurable product with value of attribute swatch, you need to have all images in configurable products and separate for simple products

Comment: I ran into an issue when trying to import the config swatches into a customer theme. I show the process i used to debug my problem in this post: http://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/132939/configurable-product-image-not-switching-with-swatch-change, it might work for you to track down your issue following my steps.

Answer (score 1):

Many times theme not configured with RWD `color swatch` , if the theme is not design by taking base of RWD theme then it may possible that your swatch want wont work,

or may be if you have installed some gallery extension then also main image wont change.

You can try below solution for this problem

1) rename your default `media.phtml` and put rwd theme `media.phtml` and check.

2) you miss this `js/lib/elevatezoom/jquery.elevateZoom-3.0.8.min.js` file in your header for product page , please add this line in your local.xml file

```
<catalog_product_view>

    <reference name="head">

        <action method="addItem"><type>skin_js</type><script>js/lib/elevatezoom/jquery.elevateZoom-3.0.8.min.js</script></action>

    </reference>

    <reference name="product.info.media">

        <block type="core/text_list" name="product.info.media.after" as="after" />

    </reference>

</catalog_product_view>
```

in your head section of product page.

3) also  add below code in your local.xml

```
<default>

    <reference name="head">

            <action method="addJs"><script>lib/jquery/jquery-1.10.2.min.js</script></action>
            <action method="addJs"><script>lib/jquery/noconflict.js</script></action>

            <action method="addItem"><type>skin_js</type><name>js/lib/modernizr.custom.min.js</name></action>
            <action method="addItem"><type>skin_js</type><name>js/lib/selectivizr.js</name></action>
            <action method="addItem"><type>skin_js</type><name>js/lib/matchMedia.js</name></action>
            <action method="addItem"><type>skin_js</type><name>js/lib/matchMedia.addListener.js</name></action>
            <action method="addItem"><type>skin_js</type><name>js/lib/enquire.js</name></action>
            <action method="addItem"><type>skin_js</type><name>js/app.js</name></action>
            <action method="addItem"><type>skin_js</type><name>js/lib/jquery.cycle2.min.js</name></action>
            <action method="addItem"><type>skin_js</type><name>js/lib/jquery.cycle2.swipe.min.js</name></action>
            <action method="addItem"><type>skin_js</type><name>js/slideshow.js</name></action>
            <action method="addItem"><type>skin_js</type><name>js/lib/imagesloaded.js</name></action>
    <action method="addItem"><type>skin_js</type><name>js/minicart.js</name></action>

    </reference>

</default>
```

If files were missing then copy those files from RWD theme to your theme

Comment: I've bought theme which supports color swatches. Here's example https://shopper.queldorei.com/women/configurable-product.html of a product from that theme. Should I take actions you've written ?

Comment: @Marijus Have you apply new security patch 8788 ?

Comment: @Marijus you can try my way and check what is the problem

Comment: Tried these steps you've written however it did not help. Any idea how can I debug this problem ?

Comment: @Marijus without looking your backend configuration its hard to tell whats wrong

Comment: I've added you on linked in. Can you please respond to me on linkedin ?

Answer (score 1):

Check this URL to configure magento default swatch properly : [Change product image for configurable products](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/4482/change-product-image-for-configurable-products)

**Note :** If the theme is not designed based on RWD theme or if you have installed any module/extension for swatch then it may possible that your default magento swatch will not work.

Comment: The theme supports configurable swatches. I've set up everything like in that tutorial.